# Render page after ajax request

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, rest, playframework

I'm using HightCharts library to draw some charts under Play Framework. I've set up an ajax request when the user click on the chart. The request returns a Result with a page rendered. I'd like to perform a redirect to the rendered page.

This is the snippet code of my request:

```
plotOptions:{
                        column:{
                            colorByPoint: true
                        },
                        series: {
                            cursor: 'pointer',
                            point: {
                                events: {
                                    click: function (event) {
                                        var jsonMsg = JSON.stringify({category: data.categories[event.point.y], product: data.products[event.point.x]});
                                        $.ajax({
                                            type: 'POST',
                                            url: '@namespace.controllers.modules.routes.MailchimpController.createSegmentByCorrelation()',
                                            data: jsonMsg,
                                            contentType : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                                            dataType: 'json'
                                        });
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

And this is my return statement:

```
return ok(template.render(
                            RolesDao.getRole(session().get("role")),
                            session("email"),
                            Template.getList(apikey),
                            segmentId.toString()));
```

Any ideas about how I can do it?

Comment: hm what exactly you want to achieve? replace page with chart to new page from ajax ?

Comment: @biesior actually you're right. I've updated my post. (I'm not sure if this is possibile and maybe it is a bad practice.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your ajax action you don't can't return the rendered page (HTML code de facto), instead just create link to the page which will render as common `Result`.

Note: if parameters can contain sensitive data like some credentials, it's worth to add some effort, i.e. in AJAX action save the parameter set in DB or Cache with some unique ID and random security token and return the redirect URL with this ID and security token, later you'll be able to retrieve these credentials using given ID and render the view  in your target action. Security token is to prevent the crawlers from unauthorized access.

De facto using built-in cache API you can just put the `Result` within the cache, so it could be quite fast solution.

Comment: So, the best thing for me is to redirect the page I want and, if I have parameters to pass, pass them in the query string?

Comment: Edited the answer, I wouldn't use the credentials in GET params, use something which cannot be re-engineered at least to easy...